# Can you call/render a parameterized rmd report within another parameterized rmd report - rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm wondering if it is actually possible to call/render a parameterized report from within another parameterized report?

I found [this][1] but it doesn't seem to come up with a solution.

Below is a minimal example where ***main-report.rmd*** tries to call/render ***sub-report-1.rmd*** . Both reports have the same params in the YAML header.

library(here)

**sub-report-1.rmd**

````
---
title: "Secondary report to run"
output: html_document

params:
  country: "Canada"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

paste0("Hello ", params$country)
```
````

**main-report.rmd**

````
---
title: "Main report"
output: html_document

params:
  country: "France"
---

```{r run1, include=FALSE}
  rmarkdown::render(here::here("rmd", "sub-report-1.rmd"),
                    output_format = "html_document",
                    output_file="report1.html", 
                    params = list(country=params$country))


```
````

I get the following error:

> Error: params object already exists in the knit environment so can't
>   be overwritten by rend param. Execution halted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use another parameter in the render function: `envir = new.env()`. The problem is that object `params` is already used.

```
rmarkdown::render(here::here("rmd", "sub-report-1.rmd"),
                output_format = "html_document",
                output_file="report1.html", 
                params = list(country=params$country),
                envir = new.env())
```

Comment: Thanks @J_F.  Just to confirm, using this will mean that any variables created in the sub-report-rmd will not be available for use in main-report.rmd (unless loaded manually from a saved rds).

Comment: That is annoying, did you find another solution outside of having to save and then reload? @Jmac